# XPages, bootstrap and checkboxes

Tags: xpages

I am trying to update a XPage that has been working for ages to bootstrap but cannot get the checkboxes to show up, let alone work! With all the other elements I just created the div's and copied the fields across.

Here is part of the old form:

[image]
really ugly, here the jazzed up bootstrap one:

[image]

already much better but, as you can see the checkbox line (it should be at "Bitte ankreuzen") is missing?

This is the old code that works without bootstrap:

```
        <xp:panel styleClass="panel-body">
            <xp:label value="Angebote" id="label8" for="checkBoxGroup1"></xp:label>


            <xp:checkBox text="betreutes Wohnen" id="checkBox2" value="#{document.produkte_2}"
                title="Im Bezirk Feldkirch wird die Betreuung in Einzelwohnungen und Wohngemeinschaften (für 2 bis 13 Personen) angeboten. Eine Betreuung ist bis zu 24 Stunden täglich möglich. Die Aufgaben des täglichen Lebens erledigen die BewohnerInnen eigenver-antwortlich mit Unterstützung der BetreuerInnen."
                checkedValue="2">                   
            </xp:checkBox>

            <xp:checkBox text="intensiv betreutes Wohnen" id="checkBox1" value="#{document.produkte_1}"
                title="Das intensive Betreuungsangebot für Menschen mit psychischen Beeinträchtigungen zeichnet sich unter anderem durch kreativste Lösungen schwieriger Betreuungsanforderungen und einem erhöhten Einzelcoachingaufwand - bis zu neun Stunden - aus."
                checkedValue="1">
            </xp:checkBox>


            <xp:checkBox text="unterstütztes Wohnen" id="checkBox4" value="#{document.produkte_4} "
                title="Personen ab 50 Jahren (Pflegestufe 2 bis 4) steht dieses Angebot in Frastanz zur Verfügung. Ziele sind die Beheimatung sowie das Erhalten der Ressourcen."
                checkedValue="4">
            </xp:checkBox>

            <xp:checkBox text="ambulant betreutes Wohnen" id="checkBox3" value="#{document.produkte_3}"
                title="AQUA Mühle Vorarlberg bietet seit Herbst 2011 eine ambulante Betreuung für Menschen mit psychischen Beeinträchtigungen in ihren eigenen Wohnungen an."
                checkedValue="3">
            </xp:checkBox>

        <xp:checkBox text="Übergangswohnen" id="checkBox5" value="#{document.produkte_5}"
           title="Übergangswohnen"
           checkedValue="5">
        </xp:checkBox>


        </xp:panel>
```

what do I need to do to get this working in bootstrap? I do realise that it is not a very good way to process checkboxes (one field per option) but, unfortunately, I cannot change this as it is part of an application that has been running for about 10 years now :o)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bootstrap theme needs the extension library.

Select in XPages properies library ID "com.ibm.xsp.extlib.library" **and**
clean the project at menu "Project / Clean...".
Then, your checkboxes will be back.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much Knut - that was exactly the problem! Thank you!